# net::ERR_ABORTED NGINX EC2 Linux

Tags: linux, nginx, amazon-ec2

I am trying to get my Nginx server up and running but get ERR_Aborted error when 
trying to load the page.

[image]

My server is an EC2 Amazon Linux AMI and my Ember.js is stored in 
/distelli/envs/Production/dist/;

My NGINX.conf file:

```
server {
listen 80;
    root /distelli/envs/Production/dist/;

     # server_name ember.app;
    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    # include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
     try_files $uri /index.html;

    }

location /assets/{
    }
```

Anyone know where i am going wrong?